# "\[" bug in MongoDB 2.2

Tags: regex, mongodb

I run following queries on a collection that have a lot of entry that contains `[` and `]`.

```
 db.test.find({word:/[\[]/});           // could not be run in console
 db.test.find({word:/\[/ });            // could not be run in console
 db.test.find({word:/\]/});             //returns result
 db.test.find({word:/[\]]/});           //returns result
 db.test.find({word:{$regex:"\["}});    //no result
 db.test.find({word:{$regex:"\[[]"}});  //returns result
```

Why using `\[` is such strange? Is it a bug.

I am using mongodb 2.2.0, perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Works correct in my MongoDb version 2.0.3 :

```
> db.newColl.find({ word:/[\[]/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5098b7c2c1388461b656736c"), "word" : "abd[def" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5098b7c8c1388461b656736d"), "word" : "[def" }
> db.newColl.find({ word:/\[/})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5098b7c2c1388461b656736c"), "word" : "abd[def" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5098b7c8c1388461b656736d"), "word" : "[def" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not escaping the right characters, I believe you must escape special characters so that:

```
db.test.find({word : /[/ });
```

Should be:

```
db.test.find({word : /\[/ });
```

These work because of escaping:

```
db.test.find({word:/\]/});
db.test.find({word:/[\]]/});
```

In the first one you escape the special char, in the second you have a group `[]` of escaped `]`.

As for:

```
db.moin.find({moin:{$regex:"\[[]"}});
```

When not using `//` I believe it will try and match only one character however you are also using `[]` at the end, I believe this denotes for regex to match `.*` so it works.